# Pandas - Concatenating a stored list of DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have a list of dataframes:

```
alldfs
['result_14', 'result_12']
```

I would like to concatenate these, but doing so returns an error:

```
pd.concat((alldfs), ignore_index=True)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-de9203323f00> in <module>
----> 1 pd.concat((alldfs), ignore_index=True)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py in concat(objs, axis, join, ignore_index, keys, levels, names, verify_integrity, sort, copy)
    272     ValueError: Indexes have overlapping values: ['a']
    273     """
--> 274     op = _Concatenator(
    275         objs,
    276         axis=axis,

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py in __init__(self, objs, axis, join, keys, levels, names, ignore_index, verify_integrity, copy, sort)
    357                     "only Series and DataFrame objs are valid"
    358                 )
--> 359                 raise TypeError(msg)
    360 
    361             # consolidate

TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

The line runs successfully when I use:

```
pd.concat((['result_14', 'result_12']), ignore_index=True)
```

I want to use a variable expression as this is a bigger piece of a code that will concatenate other dataframes dependent on variables.

Comment: `pd.concat((['result_14', 'result_12']), ignore_index=True)` certainly fails for me.

Comment: You have a list of string not dataframe.

Comment: Why do you have an extra paranthesis? doesn't `pd.concat([result_14, result_12], ignore_index=True)` work?

Comment: Run: `print(alldfs.__class__)`  and see if you the class of "alldfs" is actually a dataframe or not

Answer (score 0):

Its seems you don't have a list of dataframes.

If you print `alldfs` you should see a sample of all the dataframes.

`pd.concat(alldfs, ignore_index=True)` should work.

Otherwise, you could try this:

`pd.concat([alldfs['result_14'], alldfs['result_12']], ignore_index=True)`